# Closing an Open Window Using MVVM Pattern, Produces System.NullReferenceException error

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to learn MVVM pattern using WPF C#. And I'm running into an error when trying to close an opened window after saving information to an sqlite database. When the command to save a new contact is raised, I am getting an error on HasAddedContact(this, new EventArgs());

Error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

My ViewModel:

```
public class NewContactViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        private ContactViewModel _contact;

        public ContactViewModel Contact
        {
            get { return _contact; }
            set { SetValue(ref _contact, value); }
        }

        public SaveNewContactCommand SaveNewContactCommand { get; set; }

        public event EventHandler HasAddedContact;

        public NewContactViewModel()
        {
            SaveNewContactCommand = new SaveNewContactCommand(this);
            _contact = new ContactViewModel();
        }

        public void SaveNewContact()
        {
            var newContact = new Contact()
            {
                Name = Contact.Name,
                Email = Contact.Email,
                Phone = Contact.Phone
            };

            DatabaseConnection.Insert(newContact);
            HasAddedContact(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
```

SaveNewContactCommand:

```
    public class SaveNewContactCommand : ICommand
    {
        public NewContactViewModel VM { get; set; }

        public SaveNewContactCommand(NewContactViewModel vm)
        {
            VM = vm;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            VM.SaveNewContact();
        }
    }
```

NewContactWindow.Xaml.Cs code behind:

```
public partial class NewContactWindow : Window
    {
        NewContactViewModel _viewModel;

        public NewContactWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _viewModel = new NewContactViewModel();
            DataContext = _viewModel;
            _viewModel.HasAddedContact += Vm_ContactAdded;
        }

        private void Vm_ContactAdded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Adding additional code where I call the new window:

```
public class ContactsViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<IContact> Contacts { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<IContact>();
        public NewContactCommand NewContactCommand { get; set; }

        public ContactsViewModel()
        {
            NewContactCommand = new NewContactCommand(this);

            GetContacts();
        }

        public void GetContacts()
        {
            using(var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(DatabaseConnection.dbFile))
            {
                conn.CreateTable<Contact>();
                var contacts = conn.Table<Contact>().ToList();

                Contacts.Clear();
                foreach (var contact in contacts)
                {
                    Contacts.Add(contact);
                }
            }
        }

        public void CreateNewContact()
        {
            var newContactWindow = new NewContactWindow();
            newContactWindow.ShowDialog();

            GetContacts();
        }
    }
```

ContactsWindow.Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Contacts_App.View.ContactsWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Contacts_App.View"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Contacts_App.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Contacts Window" Height="320" Width="400">

    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:ContactsViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel Margin="10">
        <Button 
            Content="New Contact"
            Command="{Binding NewContactCommand}"/>
        <TextBox Margin="0,5,0,5"/>
        <ListView
            Height="200"
            Margin="0,5,0,0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

NewContactWindow.Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Contacts_App.View.NewContactWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Contacts_App.View"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Contacts_App.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="New Contact Window" Height="250" Width="350">

    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:NewContactViewModel x:Key="vm"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel 
            Margin="10">
            <Label Content="Name" />
            <TextBox 
                Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}, Path=Contact.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
            <Label Content="Email" />
            <TextBox 
                Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}, Path=Contact.Email, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
            <Label Content="Phone Number" />
            <TextBox 
                Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}, Path=Contact.Phone, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
            <Button 
                Content="Save"
                Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}, Path=SaveNewContactCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Always check to see if an event handler such as `HasAddedContact` is null, before you raise the event. It will be null if there are no handlers. You can also call `Invoke()` on it with the null-conditional operator: `HasAddedContact?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());`. That will check `HasAddedContact` for null, and only call the method if it's not null. **But why is there no handler?** Most likely, you created an extra instance of the viewmodel somewhere, and you're invoking the command on the wrong instance. Is that the case? Can you show the code where you create and show the window?

Comment: Hi Ed Plunkett, I edited my original entry, and added where I am calling the new window from CreateNewContact().

Comment: If `HasAddedContact` has no handlers when it's raised, you must be creating another instance of `NewContactViewModel` somewhere, and somehow making that the DataContext of the create contact dialog. Put a breakpoint on the line where you raise the event. Is it null there? Put a breakpoint in the `NewContactViewModel` constructor. Is it called twice? The bug isn't in the code you've shown me. Or maybe `DatabaseConnection` is null.

Comment: Good Call! It's actually crashing on `newContactWindow.ShowDialog()` in `CreatenewContact()` under the `ContactsViewModel`. Same error as before, but I am unsure why.  You mentioned I am creating another instance, but how would that be? Sorry, I'm very new to this concept, so trying to learn all I can.  Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: Are you saying it's crashing in a different place now because you made some change, or it always crashed in CreateNewContact(), never when you raised the `HasAddedContact` event? I can tell you what's happening: Something is null and you're doing something with it. I don't know where, I don't have a [full working code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You have to find out where and what. I told you how to find out how many times that constructor is called: Put a breakpoint in the constructor. "How would that be"? How would I know?! I haven't seen that code!

Comment: You need to provide complete, accurate, and unambiguous information. It's a frustrating waste of time to throw questions and guesses at somebody and get partial, ambiguous responses. I don't think I'm going to be able to help you with the kind of information you're willing to provide.

Comment: I put a break on `HasAddedContact`, the value for `this` is not null. I put a break in the constructor for `NewContactViewModel` and it's indeed being called twice. The first time it's called on `InitializeComponent()` within the `Public NewContactWindow()` constructor, and again on `_viewModel = New NewContactViewModel();` within the same constructor.

Comment: Please add the XAML for the window to your question. Do you have something like  `<Window.DataContext><local:NewContactViewModel /></Window.DataContext>`? That's the classic way for new WPF programmers to create an unwanted extra viewmodel.

Comment: I edited the above entry to include both XAML files. The line of code in NewContactWindow.xaml is `<Window.Resources><vm:NewContactViewModel x:Key="vm"/></Window.Resources>`.

Comment: What is this `{Binding Source={StaticResource vm}`?! Oh, my God! Kill it with fire, everywhere. Kill it with fire! Where did you get that idea from?! You create a datacontext in your constructor. Here, I'll write an answer. Oh my God. Oh my dear God.

Comment: Definitely a learning experience, lol.  I removed the `Source={StaticResource vm}` and the `<Window.Resources><vm:NewContactViewModel x:Key="vm"/></Window.Resources>`. And that seems to be working now!

Comment: Excellent! Glad we got that sorted.

Comment: Thank you again!

Comment: Any time. 
My pleasure!

Comment: Handling UI controls in view model is not MVVM conform. The view model should not depend on the view. Since you are referencing and instantiating `NewContactWindow`, you introduced this dependency. MVVM was created to lift this direction of dependencies. If MVVM is a pattern, then your implementation is anti-pattern.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what should be done then please? I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating NewContactWindow's viewmodel in the constructor, correctly assigning it to DataContext, and correctly adding a handler to that event. Unfortunately, you also create a second instance of the same viewmodel in resources, and you manually set the Source property of all the bindings to use the one in the resources, which doesn't have the event handler.

`Window.DataContext`, which you set in the constructor, is the default Source for any binding in the Window XAML. Just let it do its thing. I also removed all the redundant `Mode=TwoWay` things from the Bindings to `TextBox.Text`, since that property is defined so that all bindings on it will be TwoWay by default. I don't think `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is doing anything necessary or helpful either: That causes the Binding to update your viewmodel property every time a key is pressed, instead of just when the TextBox loses focus. But I don't think you're doing anything with the properties where that would matter; there's no validation or anything. But TextBox.Text *is* one of the very few places where that's actually used, so I left it in.

You should remove the analagous viewmodel resource in your other window. It's not doing any harm, but it's useless at best. At worst, it's an attractive nuisance. Kill it with fire and bury the ashes under a lonely crossroads at midnight.

```
<Window x:Class="Contacts_App.View.NewContactWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Contacts_App.View"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Contacts_App.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="New Contact Window" Height="250" Width="350">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel 
            Margin="10">
            <Label Content="Name" />
            <TextBox 
                Text="{Binding Contact.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
            <Label Content="Email" />
            <TextBox 
                Text="{Binding Contact.Email, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
            <Label Content="Phone Number" />
            <TextBox 
                Text="{Binding Contact.Phone, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
            <Button 
                Content="Save"
                Command="{Binding SaveNewContactCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```